# Need to connect 2 Raspberry Pis to send to each other HD video - what is the best way?

Tags: raspicam

So I want to use 2 Raspberry Pis with cameras and transfer the HD video stream (720p at minimum) to each other so I can process the video faster using the 2 GPUs.

What is the best way to send data from 2 Raspberry Pis USB, IO Pins, DSI (somehow) or other?
My goals is that the 2 Raspberry Pis do some Pre-video processing like some basic color comparison (because in my case i want 1 Pi camera and 1 Pi NoIR camera so the Pis can differentiate between infrared and "normal" light, for exemple and other thing and then they send the stereo video to a PC that can do the heavy work (range finding 3D object recognition ...), and the communication needs to be with low latency.

Comment: You might want to clarify what you mean by "process".   I don't know to what extent you can defer, e.g., minimally H264 encoding (which I think is pretty minimal), without writing your own version of raspivid.

Comment: I don't get it. Two Pis, two cameras, some data transfer, and somehow processing is going to be faster?

Comment: I mean video processing like stereo vison distance finder and some basic video enchanting etc. like one gpu is not enough

Comment: @TomásMartins, feel free to edit your question to provide any clarification that might help answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My goals is that the 2 Raspberry Pis do some Pre-video processing like some basic color comparison

I think this is really post processing -- you want to work on video that is already encoded in some comprehensible, portable format such as H264.

In this case, if the processing is fairly intensive, you may benefit from offloading it to another pi but don't bother looking beyond **ethernet**, which is sufficient to transmit as high a data rate as the pi camera can produce anyway. Wifi should also be fine as long as you are in decent proximity to the router.

However, if the ultimate goal is processing on a PC, I doubt it is worth bothering with 2 stages.  A 3 Ghz intel based quad-core PC is, for many or most purposes, not simply the obvious (3.0 * 4) / (0.9 * 4) times faster.  It is more like 10 or 20 times faster. You should be able to easily test whatever you are doing this way, of course.

Comment: So, i can use a compute module the 2 cameras and stream the video to the other pc fast enough that i have low latency ( < 15 ms) ?

Comment: It would be the same as the latency of the medium; 15 ms application-to-application via network on a multitasking OS is asking a bit much, think more like 150 ms.  *If you want realtime, military weapons system type stuff, obviously the raspberry pi is not the right platform* -- and TBH you would be well out of your league and I suspect your budget at that point.  So you might as well go with the flow of reality here.